# Get computer OS version

Tags: powershell

This script is working fine to get the OS version. I need to know who to get only Microsoft Windows 10 Pro in the result

```
$Computers = Get-Content C:\computerlist

Foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{ 


Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction  SilentlyContinue | Select-Object CSName, Caption | sort CSName


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understandy you correctly, but I think you need [Where-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee177028.aspx):

```
$Computers = Get-Content C:\computerlist

Foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{ 
  Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction  SilentlyContinue | Select-Object CSName, Caption | where Caption -eq "Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" | sort CSName
}
```

Comment: Yes that what i need to accomplish thanks Ocaso. I'm sorry my english is bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the `Caption` value, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption`:

```
foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction  SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
}
```

Comment: maybe i didn't explain my self correctly sorry for my bad english. What i'm trying to accomplish with this powershell is to find what computer are using window 10 i don't want all the windows 7 and 8 in the result but just the windows 10